# Matching attribute sets using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki

This question is about finding matching `candidate` and `path` using a triple store with SPARQL endpoint (Fuseki 3.8.0).

The matching criteria is that the `attribute`'s of a `candidate` must contain all of the `requires` of a `path`.  In the minimal example data below, the matches should be `candi_1` with `path_1` and `candi_2` with `path_2`.

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/app#> .

:candi_1
  a :candidate ;
  :attribute "A", "B", "C" .

:candi_2
  a :candidate ;
  :attribute "C", "D" .

:candi_3
  a :candidate ;
  :attribute "C", "E" .

:path_1
  a :path ;
  :requires "A", "C" .

:path_2
  a :path ;
  :requires "C", "D" .
```

The result should be:

```
+------------+-------------+
| ?candidate | ?valid_path |
+------------+-------------+
| :candi1    | :path1      |
| :candi2    | :path2      |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You will almost certainly find this easier to accomplish (and understand) if you express your data in Turtle, which looks much like SPARQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kind of double negation:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.com/app#> 

SELECT ?cand ?path
WHERE {
  ?cand a :candidate . 
  ?path a :path . 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?path :requires ?attr .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?cand :attribute ?attr .
    }
  }
}
```

The above query shouldn't be very performant. Try also the following one:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.com/app#> 

SELECT ?cand ?path
{
    {
    SELECT (COUNT(?attr) AS ?count) ?path ?cand
        {
        ?path a :path ; :requires ?attr .
        ?cand a :candidate ; :attribute ?attr . 
        } GROUP BY ?path ?cand
    } 
    {
    SELECT (COUNT(?attr) AS ?count) ?path
        {
        ?path a :path ; :requires ?attr .
        } GROUP BY ?path
    }
}
```

However, the latter query shouldn't work if "empty" candidates and paths exist.

Comment: The second counts the number of `:attribute` of shared between a `:path` and `:candidate`, then counts the `:attribute` of the `:path`.    I'm a little less clear on how this functions to restrict the response to only the counts that match.  The counts are being required to mach because both are being assigned to `?count`, correct?

Comment: @ColinGross, Yes, they are "joined", just like in regular triple patterns. Alternatively, one could write something like `FILTER(?path1 = ?path2)`.